# VBA ODBC Update

Tags: sql, vba, odbc, sql-update

This is the code I'm using to update an SQL database:

```
Public Sub main()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    cnn.Open "ConnectionName"
    rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer

    rst.Source = "Update Table ..."
    rst.Open

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I want to know is if and how I should deal with the rst object after opening it.  Do I close it?  When I try doing rst.Close, I get the error: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed".  The code works fine without rst.Close, I'm wondering if there are any dangers to not closing the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `UPDATE` operation does not return a resultset. Therefore, if executed with a `Recordset` object, it results in an empty and closed recordset. It cannot be closed anyway because it has never been opened.

A rule of thumb is:

```
if rst.State <> adStateClosed then rst.Close
```

But, because you are executing a command that's not going to return data anyway, the preferred way is:

```
dim cm as ADODB.Command
set cm = new adodb.command
set cm.activeconnection = cnn
cm.commandtype = adCmdText
cm.commandtext = "UPDATE ..."

cm.execute ,, adExecuteNoRecords
```

Or, if your SQL is a fixed string that doesn't have parameters,

```
cnn.execute "UPDATE ...",, adExecuteNoRecords
```

Also, please change `rst.ActiveConnection = cnn` to `Set rst.ActiveConnection = cnn`.

Answer (score 0):

An update returns no rows, so no need to open a recordset.

You can execute the statement directly using:

`Connection.Execute "Update Table ...", [flags]`

To answer your question, after `.Open` the recordset is closed (its `.state` will be `adStateClosed`) as no data has been returned, so setting it to nothing is sufficent.